# Can't get Podman to run on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, service, podman, podman-compose

I've installed Podman on Ubuntu using apt-get successfully, and it is running when I do:

```
service podman start
service podman status
```

The result is:

```
podman.service - Podman API Service
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/podman.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-09-23 08:19:43 CEST; 2s ago
TriggeredBy: ● podman.socket
```

So all is good. But it seems something is wrong because when I run:

```
podman system connection ls
```

to get the port used by Podman, I get an empty response. So no port is exposed. Moreover, whenever I try to deploy a simple container, I get an error message so something is definitely wrong.

Can someone please help? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```bash
podman info
```

to get more informations on your installation,

Otherwise if you are building podman using a docker image, I use these steps and I am able to run all podman operations:

- Build podman image with Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update -y

# install podman
ENV VERSION_ID=20.04

# Podman related package
RUN apt-get install -y curl wget gnupg2

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install curl wget gnupg2 -y && . ./etc/os-release && sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_${VERSION_ID}/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable.list" && wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable/xUbuntu_${VERSION_ID}/Release.key -O- | apt-key add - && apt-get update -y && apt-get -y install podman
```

- Start container in privileged mode

```bash
docker run -it --privileged podman:$TAG /bin/bash
```

- Start podman operations with specifying mount options,

For example:

```bash
podman images --storage-opt mount_program=/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs
```